# I am trying to implement a datapath using sequential logic . Trying to implement this C program

Tags: digital-logic, computer-architecture

[image]

I was thinking of creating three registers , namely X, Y and Z. I initialize x and y to constants of '0', then I make register Z an active low register. I send a constant ' 0 ' to the input line of that register, and not the input. So it sends a 1 to the Write , Read Enable of the register so it doesn't function when it's high. I'm a bit confused on how to implement the rest of the code. Any ideas (even altering what I've thought about) is welcome! Thank you!

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tSaV.png]

Comment: I hope you understand that introducing registers and needing the concept of a sequential process delineated by tests and actions means that you no longer have a purely combinatorial circuit.

Comment: Oh yeah. That bit escaped me.

Comment: the use of \$ \neq \$ is not standard C and many compilers would not understand it.  Use '!=', without the quotes, instead.

Comment: @WarrenHill I'd be more interested which compiler supports that!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not sure if any do but there may be one I have not used that does.  I'm assuming the OP has tested this code on something though I may be wrong.

Comment: @WarrenHill *cough* yeah, they probably did. It's just because also, `void main` is unusual – C99 *allows* that, but it's still strange.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I use `void main` to indicate code that never terminates.  This would only be embedded code as anything running under Linux, iOS or Windows, for example should terminate and return `int`.

Comment: @WarrenHill point is that the C standard defines what valid signatures of `main`, and `int` is the recommended one, but others are also allowed. So, all compilers support `int main(){}`, not all something else. For example, clang warns: `warning: return type of 'main' is not 'int' [-Wmain-return-type]`, and so does GCC with `-Wall` (which I **really** do on my embedded builds): `main.c:1:6: warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’ [-Wmain]` (NB: on embedded, I often use `main` out of convenience, but there's no reason – you're not having a proper libc, anyways, so hook whatever you want)

Comment: oh man, the longer I look at this, the less I'm convinced that whoever wrote this C code actually *used* C.

Comment: What is the size (number of bits) of your variables? That greatly determines the total complexity.

Comment: Isn't it obvious to everyone that the OP is trying to cheat on their homework?

Comment: @JayEye: Yes, that's why we're only giving hints, not direct answers.

Comment: Why do you need to take screenshots of imgur?

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple combinatorial solution (no registers), but you may need to work through a few examples to see it.

Here's a hint: The final value of y = z & ~1

The final value of x is more complicated, but similar.

Here's a simpler example that demonstrates the general principle. What is the final value of b?

```
a = 5;
b = 0;
while (a) {
  ++b;
  --a;
}
```

Comment: Two more hints : loop unrolling, constant folding.